# Error sintax UIColor(CGColor: selectedButton?.layer.backgroundColor) Swift

Tags: swift, uicolor, cgcolor

I am trying to follow a swift tutorial but I have the latest version and the tutorial is in the previous version. I can not solve the syntax because I do not know much about swift, I'm starting.

Line:
`let color = UIColor(CGColor: selectedButton?.layer.backgroundColor)`

Error:

> Value of optional type CGColor= not unwrapped; did yoy mean to use '!' or '?' Replace selectedButton?.layer.backgroundColor with '(selectedButton?.layer.backgroundColor)!'

I already replaced  for this:

```
let color = UIColor(CGColor: (selectedButton?.layer.backgroundColor)!)
```

next error now:

> Ambiguous use of 'init(CGColor)'

Comment: You have a typo in your code. The correct method is `UIColor(cgColor:)`. You should rely on Xcode's autocompletion is you're unsure about a method signature.

Comment: Thanks! I can solved this error.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do it would be

```
if let color = selectedButton.backgroundColor {
    // use color in here

}
```

But for tutorial purposes just use

```
let color = selectedButton.backgroundColor!
```